# How I can see my Object Inspector in Xcode again?

Tags: xcode

I'm new in development with iOS in Xcode and now I don't find the inspector again. I'm not sure what the name is of this inspector. This is the reason why I can't search a solution for my problem.

[image: What is the Name of this Inspector and how I can see this again?]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **Document Outline**. You can display it again by clicking on this little icon in the bottom-left corner of Interface Builder:

[image: Show Document Outline button]

Alternatively, you can switch it on by navigating to **Editor/Show Document Outline**.

[image: Editor/Show Document Outline]